# Alsalib mmap direct write

Tags: linux, audio, mmap, alsa

I am just messing around with ALSA library and can't really figure out how to do playback with a direct write.
I am using `SND_PCM_ACCESS_MMAP_INTERLEAVED`.
I am trying to write a square wave.

I created a buffer of shorts to hold the square wave. I have tested it with `snd_pcm_writei` and it works.

I then call `snd_pcm_begin` and use the pointers given from area to write to the device:

```
while(1)
{
  int msg;
  frames_available = snd_pcm_avail_update(handle);
  snd_pcm_mmap_begin(handle,&areas,&offset,&limit_frames);

  frames_to_write = frames; //frames is the size of the buffer in frames

  if (frames_to_write > limit_frames)
    frames_to_write = 0;
    
  int offset_frames = (areas[0].first + offset*areas[0].step)/16;
  short* write_ptr = (short*)areas[0].addr + offset_frames;

  // fill the buffer with stuff
  for(int i =0; i < frames_to_write;i++)
  {
     write_ptr[i] = buffer[i];
  }

  msg = snd_pcm_mmap_commit(handle,offset,frames_to_write);
}
```

The sound produced is choppy and gets cut off soon after. It gets cut off because the limit_frame reaches 0. I notice that limit_frames stays at 0 even if there are frames_available.

EDIT:
I used `memcpy()` instead of a for loop and that solved the choppiness. Still gets cut off though. Now I'm curious why memcpy() solves the choppiness. Shouldn't the for loop and memcpy and for loop copy over the memory contiguously?

Answer (score 0):

Using mmap does not make sense if all you're doing is copying the samples from another buffer; that's exactly the same what `snd_pcm_writei()` does.

Anyway, before calling `snd_pcm_mmap_begin()`, you *must* set its last parameter to the number of frames you intend to write, and when it returns a smaller number, you should write that number, instead of 0.

When you have more than one channel, a frame is larger than one sample.